# Trying to restrict movement of player without causing it to fly off the screen

Tags: game-engine, physics

So I'm making a three-dimensional danmakufu game in Blender. I'm trying to restrict the player's movement so that someone can't just barrel through the level.

I have currently restricted his movement to a lidless box that is 6 units 'X' by 18 units 'Y' by 2 units 'Z'. All forms of bounding cause the player to be sent flying out of the screen. Can someone help me please? The box moves -.0025 units x per second.
[image: a markup of the game in which those with screen readers cannot see that I've pointed out the bounds, player, loop and enemy]
This is only with dynamic or body physics. If using static physics, the player can just go through the barrier.

AND STOP POSTING ANSWERS IN THE COMMENTS

Currently, with the bounding box set to Rigid Body with x-translation enabled and the player as a dynamic object with all degrees of freedom stripped (and neither had collisions on in the first place!) the player is instantly flung off in the direction of positive x, negative y.

Here have some more pictures!
[image: top]
[image: bottom]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by restrict their movements? I'm just having a hard time picturing what this situation looks like right now>.

Comment: I've tried Triangle Mesh. I've tried Convex Hull. I've even tried it with different objects: simply stick a ball into a cube with either bounding mesh that is lacking a face, and the ball goes pchooo and is sent flying x-wards at velocity y or even teleported out.

Comment: it doesn't  even fall: it's meant to hold a z-position and stay there inside the 6x18 box. Different settings can have the player spazzing out and being sent x-wards, being warped out who-knows-where, or even utterly unaffected and ignored by the box!

Comment: psst: @X-27, I'd have upvoted your answer if you'd actually answered. I'd also have added gifs if I could.

Comment: @Nefer007 just realized your were a fellow "worldbuilder". i think the problem is the box is rigid body.

Comment: THIS IS A SCHOOL ASSIGNMENT AND I NEED AN ACTUAL ANSWER FAST. @VinceScalia: If it's NOT rigid body, it's NOT effected by the box.

Comment: Well, sure it is, and active physics type should do it, try dynamic.

Comment: does the water have collision? it needs to be "ghosted".

Comment: @VinceScalia: it's not water. The land itself lacks collision. I'm trying to make it so that the player's ship will run into the box wall and STAY THERE. The second and third pictures are showing exactly what happens (if only because I bound a light.) The exact thing happens if it's switched to soft, static or dynamic. However, if both are set to dynamic with triangle mesh, the rocket... actually rockets off... like a rocket. If the player is a rigid body, the box will land on top of them and slowly slink off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23849/discussion-between-nefer007-and-vince-scalia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box is having weird collision with the player, you can probably see this happening if you use "physics visualization".

[image]

To solve, switch the physics type of the box to "static" and have it clamp to the travel path that it needs to glide along. I made a working [.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36090) aside from the "clamp to" because I'm not sure of your situation.